# Is there a way to access variables that weren't defined yet in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, generator, p5.js

**Hello!**

I am trying to make a dungeon generation program like the one on BlackThornProd's channel, except in p5.js. I have a spawner function that handles spawning other rooms, I have all the rooms as functions, and I have 4 arrays that store the different rooms. My problem is, I have to access the arrays in the spawner functions, but the spawner functions have to be above the room functions, and the room functions have to be above the arrays. Like this:

```
var spawner = function(x, y, value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 1:
            topRooms[random(0, topRooms.length)](x, y);
            break;
        case 2:
            bottomRooms[random(0, bottomRooms.length)](x, y);
            break;
        case 3:
            leftRooms[random(0, leftRooms.length)](x, y);
            break;
        case 4:
            rightRooms[random(0, rightRooms.length)](x, y);
            break;
    }
};

var start = function(x, y) {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y);
    rect(-25, -25, 20, 1); //Top Left
    rect(25, -25, -20, 1); //Top Right
    rect(25, 25, -20, 1); //Bottom Right
    rect(-25, 25, 20, 1); //Bottom Left
    rect(25, -25, 1, 20); //Right Top
    rect(25, 25, 1, -20); //Right Bottom
    rect(-25, 25, 1, -20); //Left Bottom
    rect(-25, -25, 1, 20); //Left Top
    popMatrix();
};

var topRooms = [];
var bottomRooms = [];
var leftRooms = [];
var rightRooms = [];
```

As you can see, the arrays have to be accessed from the spawners, which are above the arrays. I don't know if there is a way to access stuff that is below the code, but the environment I'm using doesn't like it.

If you know of a solution, please respond. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Arrays declared with *var* keyword are *hoisted* so even if you declare them later, them will be moved on the top of the script anyway.

If your code is incomplete (I do not see where arrays are populated) maybe your issue is when trying to call the function inside them.

This can be solved by a simple check before invoking the function:

```
case 1:
  topRooms[random(0, topRooms.length)] && topRooms[random(0, topRooms.length)](x, y);
  break;
```

Comment: I was testing this out in the KhanAcademy editor (probably not the best place =D) and it gives me this error: "'topRooms' was used before it was defined." There are also matching errors for each of the other arrays. Maybe it's only in the KhanAcademy editor?

Comment: maybe that's a linter issue, because hoisting of _var_ is a fact

Comment: arrays are holding functions ?